# Tomcat/WildFly - fast webapp auto-reload on IDE compile-on-save?

Tags: junit4, java-ee-7

Is it possible to do what "mvn jetty:run" does, ie. run it against an extracted webapp and auto-reload/auto-restart the webapp if any of the extracted files have been changed?

Beware! I'm *NOT* talking about updated WAR files and auto-deploying them. My IDEs currently update the class files directly inside the "extracted" webapp file structure.

Context: I'm wondering what (freely licensed, ie apache/lgpl, not CDDL/GPL) Java EE 7 solution provides the fastest roundtrip times for developing test units against the full stack/bugfixing.

I'm also thinking about continuing to use Jetty 9.4, maybe with openejb, because I'm not using most of the JavaEE features anyways. I'm not really a big fan of IoC/DI because if you try to avoid scanning overhead, you put configuration into XML, whereas setting up an embedded server programmatically is strongly typed and cleaner IMHO (remember jetty.xml? programming Java using XML, wtf...). I also don't like JSTL/JSP etc. because templates feel like PHP and j2html seems much more Java-like to me.

But what I want is JPA transaction handling/connection pools for my Jersey servlets. Currently I'm doing that inside a RequestListener, and a more seamless support seems preferable, though not at the cost of being able to run a full stack jetty embedded server in my unit tests without much hassle.

### Update

I'm using a simple BASH script using inotifywait now. It simply uses Glassfish's and WildFly's RESTful admin consoles for redeploy:

https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/snippets/blob/master/bash/jee_autodeploy.sh

It doesn't even deploy the war, instead it simply deploys the build directory. It should be fast enough for most use cases. And if your app grows too large and increases reload times beyond a certain point, one should probably start thinking about refactoring it into multiple modules anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using OpenLiberty, which was released today and is the core (Java EE 7 complaint) subset of WebSphere Liberty.  It comes with an eclipse plugin known as "WebSphere Developer tools" and is under the EPL-1.0 license.

http://openliberty.io/